# ResultSet getDate() is returning incorrect and correct dates

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I am creating a list of LocalDate's from a table of holidays. The dates are all correct in the database table, but when I use the ResultSet getDate() method and populate a list with all the dates 4 of the dates are wrong and 6 are correct. I am looking for any help figuring out why this is the case.

```
final LocalDate currentDay = LocalDate.now();
final List<LocalDate> holidays = getHolidays(currentDay);

//This method takes in a date and calculates the holidays that occur that year
public static List<LocalDate> getHolidays(final LocalDate date) {
 final List<LocalDate> holidayList = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();

 try {
   final PreparedStatement holidaysByYearQuery = conn.prepareStatement(
      "SELECT fulldate FROM holidays WHERE YEAR(fulldate) = ?");

    holidaysByYearQuery.setObject(1, date.getYear());

    final ResultSet holidaysByYearResult = holidaysByYearQuery.executeQuery();

    while (holidaysByYearResult.next()) {
      final Date holidate = (Date) holidaysByYearResult.getObject(1);
      final LocalDate holiday = holidate.toLocalDate();
      holidayList.add(holiday);
    }
  } catch (final SQLException e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not query holiday table: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  return holidayList;
 }

// This is the query used in Java:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement@1c27c773: SELECT fulldate FROM holidays WHERE YEAR(fulldate) = 2019

// Here is the list that is returned from the method
[2018-12-31, 2019-02-17, 2019-04-19, 2019-05-20, 2019-07-01, 2019-08-05, 2019-09-02, 2019-10-14, 2019-12-24, 2019-12-25]
```

Here is the database table information. It is very basic.

```
CREATE TABLE holidays( 
province VARCHAR(255), 
holiday VARCHAR(255), 
fulldate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO holidays(province, holiday, fulldate) VALUES
('Ontario', 'New Years', '2019-01-01'), 
('Ontario', 'Family Day', '2019-02-18'), 
('Ontario', 'Good Friday', '2019-04-19'), 
('Ontario', 'Victoria Day', '2019-05-20'), 
('Ontario', 'Canada Day', '2019-07-01'), 
('Ontario', 'Civic Holiday', '2019-08-05'), 
('Ontario', 'Labour Day', '2019-09-02'), 
('Ontario', 'Thanksgiving', '2019-10-14'), 
('Ontario', 'Christmas Day', '2019-12-25'), 
('Ontario', 'Boxing Day', '2019-12-26');

// This is the select result from the query above

+---------------------+
|       fulldate      |
+---------------------+
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-02-18 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-04-19 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-05-20 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-07-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-08-05 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-09-02 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-10-14 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-12-25 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2019-12-26 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

As you can see the 2 dates on each end of the list are incorrect. I assume something is happening with the getDate() method. Can anyone shed some light on this? Cheers.

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your column? And what database system are you using?

Comment: Why use DateTime as type if you are only storing a date? There is a getDate method for ResultSet. My guess is that this is about time zones and different daylight time savings changes

Comment: @BasilBourque DATETIME and Mysql(Innodb)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is just currently the schema I have now. I used DATE before and it has the exact same issue.

Comment: You are using the wrong type for a date-only value. Define your column as `DATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you mixing the terrible legacy class `Date` with the modern `LocalDate`? And why are you casting `(Date)`?

## SQL-standard `DATE`

If your column is of a type akin to the SQL-standard `DATE`, then use `LocalDate` with a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

If your column is of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, then you must account for time zone to determine a date.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

## SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

If your column is of a data type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` such as the MySQL type `DATETIME`, use the Java type `LocalDateTime`. This type has only a date and time-of-day without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this type does **not** represent a moment.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
```

[image: Table listing date-time types in Java (both modern & legacy) and in standard SQL.]

Comment: The cast was an old attempt of a solution because the resultSet.getDate() does not return a LocalDate. 

using myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ; works. Was the mixing of the Date and LocalDate what was causing those few dates to be offset?

I also, appreciate the info on the with & without timezones. It seems like a much more robust solution.

Comment: @RWri - The `Date` values were incorrect for dates where Eastern Standard Time (EST) would be in effect. EDT started on 2019-03-10 and will end on 2019-11-03. The default behaviour for JDBC is to associate a `java.sql.Date` with the default time zone for the JVM unless some other time zone is specified. Apparently the date/time value for New Year's Day was being returned as `2018-12-31 23:00:00 EST` and that was being truncated to `2018-12-31`.

Comment: @GordThompson Interesting. Do you have an idea why it was only incorrect on 4/10 of the dates. If it was caused by timezones, I would expect all the dates to be offset.

Comment: @RWri re: "If it was caused by timezones, I would expect all the dates to be offset." - Not necessarily. Things can get confusing when, for example, your JVM is using the `America/Toronto` time zone (which respects EST/EDT) and the MySQL Server is using a fixed zone offset, e.g., `UTC-4` (which does not account for Standard/Daylight time).

Comment: @GordThompson makes sense. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: The comments by Gord Thompson are correct, and show why you should never use the troublesome legacy classes such as `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, and `Calendar`.